# Laravel (Lumen) - Acting As A User In The Database

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

When testing I am able to create a model factory and then act as that user e.g.
`$users = factory(User::class)->create();
 $this->actingAs($users)`

Would it be possible for me to act as a user who is already in the database, so say I could reference their ID number and then test as that user?

Comment: Try `$users = User::find(1);` .. where `1` is the correct id. (you might have to fix the User namespace like `$users = App\Models\User::find(1);`).

Comment: Thanks that seems to work.

Comment: You can add it as an answer and accept it, or I can add it, so the question can be closed.

Comment: I'll let you add an answer seeing as you did give it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$users = User::find(1);` .. where `1` is the correct id.

You can use any Eloquent function such as `User::where('name', '=', 'John');` too.

You might have to fix the User namespace like `$users = App\Models\User::find(1);` or `use` (import) it.

Note that you can roll back your [databases](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test) after each test too, or simply use another database altogether.

Comment: Out of interest, is it possible to use find with another value like name or can it only be used for id's?